# Ant warning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing

Tags: java, ant, annotations, javac

I am receiving this warning when running an Ant build script (Ant 1.8.2, Java 1.6).

```
[javac] warning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing.
[javac] Use -proc:none to disable annotation processing or -implicit to specify a policy for implicit compilation.
[javac] 1 warning
```

Adding `<compilerarg value="implicit" />` produces:

```
[javac] error: Class names, 'implicit', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
[javac] 1 error
```

Adding `<compilerarg value="proc:none" />` produces:

```
[javac] javac: invalid flag: proc:none
[javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[javac] use -help for a list of possible options
```

Can someone shed some light on what the warning means and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: From what I can tell, the warning message means that ant is compiling some classes that were not explicitly added to a `<javac>` task via `srcdir`, a `<FileSet>` or whatever.  Those classes were probably included since explicitly included classes `import` them.  Those classes then will not have their annotations processed, e.g. `@Override`, `@Deprecated`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I create a simple build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="build" basedir=".">
    <target name="build">
        <javac destdir="bin" srcdir="." includes="**/*.java">
        </javac>
    </target>
</project>
```

With a simple .java which referenced to a custom annotation. But the source code is not offered.

```
public class T {
    @TestAnn
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

The output of **ant** command is the same as your first output. I try to execute **javac** command to compiled it, but `error: cannot find symbol @TestAnn` is printed. I don't know why the message is different.

Then I add annotation class and run **ant** command again. The build successful without warning.

For your question, the possible reason is:

- java code reference to custom annotation, but annotation class is not found
- Base on [the ANNOTATION PROCESSING seciton of javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#processing), if the annotation required processor. But their jar doesn't include service provider-configuration files. You should specify `-processorpath` or `-processor` option, so **javac** can find a proper processor.